# How do I insert data into MongoDB without using a form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I recently completed Colt Steele's "The Web Developer Bootcamp" on Udemy. I am in the midst of creating a pomodoro timer using HTML/CSS/Javascript/Bootstrap for the frontend and Node/Express/MongoDB for the backend.

I want the pomodoro data (start time, end time, duration, project) to be inserted into the database once the pomodoro session is complete but I'm not sure how to do it from the client side. For Colt's "YelpCamp" project, all the data that is added into the database is through a form.

Comment: If you are looking to insert data into the database directly you can use a GUI tool like MongoDB Compass.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply create an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) and use it to `POST` and `GET` data from the server. First of all, We'll simply create a server with nodejs and connect it with mongodb database then, we'll create two routes GET and POST, Former to fetch data and the latter to save data to a mongodb collection. Once, All of this is completed we can simply consume these APIs in our client side using either [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) or [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro).

Here's an example on how to do that.


Step 1: Create a project, Run

```
npm init -y
```

Step 2: Install dependencies

```
npm i express mongoose cors
```

Step 3: Configure your index.js

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
mongoose.connect(DB_URL, (err, db) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    let dbo = db.client.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/YourDB");
    console.log('\x1b[33mDatabase Connected!\x1b[0m');
});
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
// now you can simply create two API routes for fetching and posting data

// GET Route
app.get('/api/pomodoro', (req, res) => {
   return res.json({status: "success", message: "Fetching Pomodoro Data!", data: null});
});
// POST Route
app.post('/api/pomodoro', (req, res) => {
   const body = req.body;
   
   // Write your logic here to save data
   return res.json({
      status: "success",
      message: "Received POST Request",
      data: body
   })
});
```

Once, You can test your APIs using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) and once, it starts working you can join all pieces together to complete the puzzle.
You can simply consume these APIs with either [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) or with [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro).

You can find multiple blogs on this by simply doing a google search.



Check [this](https://medium.com/@rahulguptalive/how-to-build-simple-restful-crud-api-with-nodejs-expressjs-and-mongodb-2d25a0e27937) blog out for a detailed explanation.